# Call function inside the input tag on load

Tags: inputbox

In this input field function is called on click, age is calculated based on previous date of birth field. Can I call function onload

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) onload event for further information